# how do Insert data automatically in table when one data is created from another table one to one relationship?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

So basically i have two table with one to one realtionship.

```
Table 1: Users
    id
    username

Table 2: Wallet
    id
    totalamount
    user_id
```

But i dont know how to add wallet automatically when user is created.
Right now i've known only spring mvc so do i write insert method in DAO?

Comment: you make 2 JavaClass (java class for every Table)and use  JPA and Entity manager and JDBA . and after this you can create a Method to Insert Data . and use Save Method . if you show the code , we can make it together . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use JPA, then *Yes*, you have to handle db interactions by yourself. You can create DAO or dedicated service to write the insert methods.

If you use **[Hibernate](https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-tutorial)** as JPA and create `@Entity` classes for each table, you can achieve that by simply mentioning the `CascadeType` in the mapping.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Then just by saving 1 class, the other will be auto inserted in db. You can go for different **[CascadeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F6%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)** based on your requirement.

few other questions that you can check out -
[How to get data from oracle without jpa on spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774709/how-to-get-data-from-oracle-without-jpa-on-spring-boot)
[What is hibernate in simple language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500128/what-is-hibernate-in-simple-language)
[Hibernate: Cascade Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551485/hibernate-cascade-type)

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate, you can take advantage of cascading to simplify the process of saving related entities. In this case, you can use cascading to automatically persist the Wallet when saving a new User. Here's the example:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private String username;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Wallet wallet;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Wallet {

    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    // additional methods if needed
}
```

```
public interface WalletRepository extends JpaRepository<Wallet, Long> {
    // additional methods if needed
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WalletRepository walletRepository;

    @Transactional
    public User createUserWithWallet(User user) {
        // Save the user to generate the user ID
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        // Create a wallet for the user
        Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
        wallet.setUser(savedUser);
        walletRepository.save(wallet);

        // Set the wallet to the user and save again
        savedUser.setWallet(wallet);
        userRepository.save(savedUser);

        return savedUser;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.createUserWithWallet(user);
    }
}
```